# Can't get user email from Plumier social login with Google provider

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oauth-2.0, plumier

I created a React app with social login like [this](https://github.com/plumier/tutorial-monorepo-social-login) example, but the email field returned always `null`.

I check my configuration on the google developer console its already include `email` scope.

My auth controller is just simply like the example

```js
class AuthController {
    @oAuthCallback(new GoogleProvider(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET))
    async google(@bind.loginStatus() login: GoogleLoginStatus, state: string, @bind.cookie("csrf:key") secret: string) {

        //the login.data.email <--- always null

    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On current version `1.0.0-beta.11`, the default `scope` parameter for the google authorize endpoint (dialog endpoint) is just `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`, I will fix this issue and will be ready on the next stable release.

For workaround, you can return the `scope` parameter manually on your dialog endpoint like below

```js
export class DialogsController {

    @oAuthDialogEndPoint(new GoogleDialogProvider(<your callback>, <your client id>))
    google() {
        return { scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" }
    }
}
```

Note that the `scope` parameter is a space separated scope like described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)